# How to get custom attributes from dll in vb.net?

Tags: .net, dll, attributes

I created class file **A** contain a custom attribute named **myAttribute** like

```
<Serializable> 
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)>
Public Class myAttribute
    Inherits Attribute 
    Private m_configFileExtension As String = Nothing

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Property ConfigFileExtension() As String
        Get
            Return m_configFileExtension
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_configFileExtension = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Then I created class file **B** contain function call the myAttribute by reflection

```
Private Function AssemblyAttributes()
   Dim a As Assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType(myAttribute))
   Dim attributes As Object() = a.GetCustomAttributes(False)

   For Each obj As Object In attributes
       Dim lmc As myAttribute = TryCast(obj, myAttribute)
       If Not lmc Is Nothing Then
          'code here
       End If
   Next
End Function
```

Then I created class file **C** which add assembly header

```
<Assembly: myAttribute(ConfigFileExtension:="log.xml")>
```

Class file **A, B, C** are in same visual studio **solution 1**
Now I ran the solution and **a.GetCustomAttributes(False)** can get **myAttribute.ConfigFileExtension** string value **[log.xml]**

Then I compile and build class file **A and B** into **dll**.

Now I created another visual studio **solution 2**, I used *[Add Reference]* to add the dll which build from **solution 1** into **solution 2**

The question now is...

if I run **solution 2** , it cannot get **myAttribute's** value. But I confirmed that I already added a assembly header in **solution 2** class file:

```
<Assembly: myAttribute(ConfigFileExtension:="log.xml")>
```

Do you knew what I am missing/wrong?

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: Your Assembly.GetAssembly() call is wrong.  That returns the assembly that contains the attribute type.  Not the assembly created by solution 2.

Comment: Thanks for your response!! Did you knew how/what code to get the assembly created by solution 2?